# I/Choreographer: Skipped 9622 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-sqlite

I am running the alarmManager for which i need to fetch the data from 3 different SQLite DB and depending on the condition i need to show the notification. Notification might be more than 5 at once. And I am getting the error : Skipped 9622 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. And application will also get stopped. Is there any way to run the alarmManager to show notification in thread or async ways so that i wont harm the application performance.

Comment: How to reduced this time frame? Due to this, performance is too slow. Any solution????

Answer (score 0):

You should be:

- Using `getBroadcast()` on `PendingIntent`, to create the `PendingIntent` to pass to the methods on `AlarmManager`
- Have that broadcast `Intent` point to a subclass of `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`
- Have that receiver call `startWakefulService()`, with an `Intent` pointing to an `IntentService` where you do the work
- Have the `IntentService` call `completeWakefulIntent()` at the end of `onHandleIntent()`

This will put your work on a background thread (supplied by `IntentService`) and make it a bit more likely that your process will live long enough to do the work.

In addition, though, you really need to look at the work that you are doing. 9622 frames is ~160 seconds, or over 2.5 minutes. That's a *very* long time for your app to be busy doing something in the background, particularly if you are not blocking on network I/O or something during most of that time.

Comment: I am using like this : using getBroadcast() on pendingIntent and to pass to AlarmReceiver. And in AlaramReceiver, onReceive overrride method i am send Intent to AlarmService an In AlaramService I am sending the notification with some calculation on date. Notification is coming but not at the exact time. It might me after 6-7 mins. I am getting  Skipped 9622 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. If you want the code wise flow I can post that too. Please take me out from this issue.